# Pandas dataframe: drop all the rows based one column value with python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a dataframe df as following, I want to remove or delete the rows that name is tom, I use the following code(python3):

```
df1[~df1['name'].str.contains('tom')]
```

but there is error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'str' of 'SeriesGroupBy'   
     objects, try using the 'apply' method


name    age weight 
tom     10   40
lucy    15   50
john    20   60
tom     10   40
lucy    15   50
john    20   60
tom     10   40
kate    30   70
tick    40   75
bruce   50   75
```

Please help me to solve it, this is just example data, since the real dataframe is large size. if you guys have fast solution, please tell me. thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is saying that `df1` is a `SeriesGroupBy` object, not a DataFrame. Apparently, the DataFrame with columns `name`, `age`, `weight` is not `df1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df["name"] != 'tom']

 or 

df[~df['name'].str.contains('tom')]

To remove on multiple criteria  -- "~" is return opposite of True/False

df2[~(df2["name"].isin(['tom','lucy']))]
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but there is error: KeyError: 'Column not found: True'

Comment: hi @Merlin, how about deleting the rows that name are tom and lucy. could you help me again!

Comment: @tktktk071,  Check edit... here is tutorial  ....  https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html